# How can I restore SQL Server 2000 from corrupted backup files?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server 2000.  I have a corrupted backup file.  How can I restore the database from that corrupted backup file?  Any help or suggestions really appreciated.

Comment: Corrupted in what way? I'm not an SQL Server admin, but I suspect they are going to need details.

Comment: You might get more expert help at serverfault.com: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific error? Right now your only hope is the file is actually okay, but you aren't using the right syntax or what have you to restore it.  Products like SQL log explorer exist--which allow you to look into proprietary format of the log files, but I've never seen anything comparable for the backup file.